# How to Xor cipher_text and and hex value?

Tags: encryption, xor, bitwise-xor

How do I use python to Xor cipher-text1 XOR cipher-text2 = "3c0d094c1f523808000d09" and   "746865" to get this "48656c"? Thanks

It is based on this
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LeNz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `^` [bitwise exclusive or operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) on each byte:

```
>>> a = bytes.fromhex('3c0d094c1f523808000d09')
>>> b = bytes.fromhex('746865')
>>> bytes(x ^ y for x, y in zip(a, b)).hex()
'48656c'
```